# Cordova's 3.1 navigator.device.capture.captureVideo always call error callback with error code 3

Tags: android, cordova

Part of my  www/js/index.html file :

```
 receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var mkb = document.getElementById("make-video-button");

    mkb.addEventListener('click',function () {
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(app.captVidCall.success, app.captVidCall.error)   
    } , false);



},
captVidCall : {
    success : function () {
        alert("success");
    },
    error   : function (error) {
        alert("Error code : " + error.code);
    }
}
```

I added the media capture plugin by

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture

[ 'org.apache.cordova.camera',
'org.apache.cordova.file',
'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer',
'org.apache.cordova.media-capture' ]
```

And cordova version is :

```
 cordova --version
 3.1.0-0.1.0
```

I read somewhere that this is the bug at the cordova's side... But I can't find this again. And I can't believe that stable version 3.1 could have such severe bug.

PS : Device I test on is `Nexus 7 (2013)` with Android 4.3
(Then it call an app.captVidCall.error with error.code == 3)

When running this one the `Xperia Neo V` With Android 4.0.4 the app crashes immediately after I capture video.

(To run the the app I use

```
cordova build
cordova run android
```

)

Git repo with executable in videoAppCaptureFailure/platforms/android/bin
https://github.com/bluesm/videoAppCaptureFailure

Comment: happens to me when trying to upload photo to S3, Code 3

Answer (score 0):

Its occur because if you click on start recording and do nothing, if you click on device back  button, so that  it will be generate the error.

During error code please compare error code and if it match with no-3 than make alert function for same.

Comment: Its occur because if you click on start recording and do nothing, if you click on device back  button, so that  it will be generate the error.

During error code please compare error code and if it match with no-3 than make alert function for same.

 if(error.code == 3) {
            alert("Please record something");
        }